# How to dynamically populate the text area & Error message through Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to Jquery & Right now i have two textarea. When click on Add button, i have to dynamically add two more textarea continuously on click & have to generate the error message as well.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var counter = 1;
  
  $("#addButton").click(function() {
    var newTextBoxDiv = $(document.createElement('div')).attr("id", 'TextBoxDiv' + counter);
    newTextBoxDiv.after().html(' <textarea class="form-control" id="prodetails-prdut-nme ' + counter + '" rows="1"></textarea> <span class="prodetails-prdut-nme-error-msg pull-left color-red" style="display: none;">Must be less than 30characters.</span><div class="pull-right clr-gray" id="prodetails-prdut-nme-cnt"></div><textarea class="form-control" id="prodetails-spec" rows="1"></textarea> <span class="prodetails-spec-error-msg pull-left color-red" style="display: none;">Must be less than 50 characters.</span><div class="pull-right clr-gray" id="prodetails-spec-cnt"></div>');
    newTextBoxDiv.appendTo("#TextBoxesGroup");
    counter++;
  });
  
  $('#prodetails-prdut-nme-cnt').html(30 + ' characters remaining');
  $('#prodetails-prdut-nme').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#prodetails-prdut-nme').val().length;
    var text_remaining = 30 - text_length;
    if (text_remaining < 0) {
      $('.prodetails-prdut-nme-error-msg').show();
      $(this).addClass('cnt-error-clr');
      $('#prodetails-prdut-nme-cnt').hide();
    } else {
      $('#prodetails-prdut-nme-cnt').show();
      $(this).removeClass('cnt-error-clr');
      $('.prodetails-prdut-nme-error-msg').hide();
    }
    $('#prodetails-prdut-nme-cnt').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
  });
  
  $('#prodetails-spec-cnt').html(50 + ' characters remaining');
  $('#prodetails-spec').keyup(function() {
    var text_length = $('#prodetails-spec').val().length;
    var text_remaining = 50 - text_length;
    if (text_remaining < 0) {
      $('.prodetails-spec-error-msg').show();
      $(this).addClass('cnt-error-clr');
      $('#prodetails-spec-cnt').hide();
    } else {
      $('#prodetails-spec-cnt').show();
      $(this).removeClass('cnt-error-clr');
      $('.prodetails-spec-error-msg').hide();
    }
    $('#prodetails-spec-cnt').html(text_remaining + ' characters remaining');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class="form-control" id="prodetails-prdut-nme" rows="1"></textarea> <span class="prodetails-prdut-nme-error-msg pull-left color-red" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Must be less than 30 characters.</span>
<div class="pull-right clr-gray" id="prodetails-prdut-nme-cnt"></div>
<textarea class="form-control" id="prodetails-spec" rows="1"></textarea> <span class="prodetails-spec-error-msg pull-left color-red" style="display: none;"><i aria-hidden="true" class=
"fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> Must be less than 50 characters.</span>
<div class="pull-right clr-gray" id="prodetails-spec-cnt"></div>
<div id='TextBoxesGroup'></div>
<form>
  <input id='addButton' type='button' value='Add production capacity for more products'>
</form>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Pkprabu/4mcahd2f/1/)

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Please post some code so people can help you

Comment: Link is not clickable; also please paste all code here.

Comment: @pkprabu  you can try jquery validate

Comment: Thank you guys. But, I want to generate those error message dynamically &  If the boxes are more than one, I think its not good practice writing code for all boxes separately. Is it possible writing error message dynamically like i have shown?